# Phrase suggester returns unexpected result when first letter is misspelled

Tags: elasticsearch, solr, lucene, information-retrieval

I'm using Elasticsearch [Phrase Suggester](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-phrase.html) for correcting user's misspellings. everything is working as I expected unless user enters a query which it's first letter is misspelled. At this situation phrase suggester returns nothing or returns unexpected results.

My query for suggestion:

```
{
"suggest": {
"text": "user_query",
"simple_phrase": {
  "phrase": {
    "field": "title.phrase",,
    "collate": {
      "query": { 
        "inlile" : {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
                 { "match": {"title": "{{suggestion}}"}},
                  { "match": {"participants": "{{suggestion}}"}}
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

}
}

Example when first letter is misspelled:

```
"simple_phrase" : [
  {
    "text" : "گاشانچی",
    "offset" : 0,
    "length" : 11,
    "options" : [ {
      "text" : "گارانتی",
      "score" : 0.00253151
    }]
  }
]
```

Example when fifth letter is misspelled:

```
"simple_phrase" : [
  {
    "text" : "کاشاوچی",
    "offset" : 0,
    "length" : 11,
    "options" : [ {
      "text" : "کاشانچی",
      "score" : 0.1121
    },
    {
      "text" : "کاشانجی",
      "score" : 0.0021
    },
    {
      "text" : "کاشنچی",
      "score" : 0.0020
    }]
  }
]
```

I expect that these two misspelled queries have same suggestions(my expected suggestions are second one). what is wrong?

P.S: I'm using this feature for Persian language.

Comment: Please refer to my answer on this post
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59527443/elasticsearch-spell-check-suggestions-even-if-first-letter-missed/66796538#66796538

Answer (score 0):

> I have solution for your problem, only need to add some fields in your schema.

**P.S: I don't have that much expertise in elasticsearch but I have solved same problem using solr, you can implement same way in elasticSearch too**

> Create new ngram field and copy all you title name in ngram field.
>
> When you fire any query for missspell word and you get blank result then split 
>    the word and again fire the same query you will get results as expected.

```
Example : Suppose user searching for word Akshay but type it as Skshay, then 
create query in below way you will get results as expected hopefully.

I am here giving you solr example same way you can achieve it using 
elasticsearch.

**(ngram:"skshay" OR ngram:"sk" OR  ngram:"ks" OR ngram:"sh" OR ngram:"ha" ngram:"ay")**
```

> We have split the word sequence wise and fire query on field ngram.
>
> Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I'm wondering why this isn't working as expected? As far as I know Phrase Suggester use edit distance for correcting misspelled word, then why it does not work if first letter is misspelled? As far as I know there is no difference which letter is misspelled in edit distance algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

From Elasticsearch doc:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-suggesters-phrase.html

> prefix_length
>
> The number of minimal prefix characters that must match in order be a
> candidate suggestions. Defaults to 1. Increasing this number improves
> spellcheck performance. Usually misspellings don’t occur in the
> beginning of terms. (Old name "prefix_len" is deprecated)

So by default phrase-suggester assumes that the first character is correct because the default value for `prefix_length` is 1.

**Note:** setting this value to 0 is not a good way because this will have performance implications.
You need to use the `reverse analyzer`
I explained it in this post so please go and check my answer
[Elasticsearch spell check suggestions even if first letter missed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59527443/elasticsearch-spell-check-suggestions-even-if-first-letter-missed/66796538#66796538)

And regarding the duplicates, you can use

> skip_duplicates
> Whether duplicate suggestions should be filtered out (defaults to
> false).