# Elasticsearch spell check suggestions even if first letter missed

Tags: elasticsearch, spell-checking

I create an index like this:

```
curl --location --request PUT 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/test/' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "settings" : {
        "number_of_shards" : 1
    },
    "mappings" : {
        "properties" : {
            "word" : { "type" : "text" }
        }
    }
}'
```

when I create a document:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/test/_doc/' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{ "word":"organic" }'
```

And finally, search with an intentionally misspelled word:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/test/_search' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
  "suggest": {
    "001" : {
      "text" : "rganic",
      "term" : {
        "field" : "word"
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

The word 'organic' lost the first letter - ES never gives suggestion options for such a mispell (works absolutely fine for any other misspells - 'orgnic', 'oragnc' and 'organi'). What am I missing?

Comment: I think this is happening because of the `prefix_length` parameter: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters.html . It defaults to 1, i.e. at least 1 letter from the beginning of the term has to match. I don't yet have an answer for how to do what you want or whether it's possible with ES' suggest feature, I'll make this a full answer once I know.

Comment: The steps to reproduce work perfectly except for 1 character in the index name of your final POST, the search action itself. The target URL is `http://127.0.0.1:9200/test1/_search` but you set up index `test` throughout. I believe you meant to target index `test` rather than `test1` with the search.

Comment: You're right, Emanuil, I've corrected

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is happening because of the `prefix_length` parameter: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters.html . It defaults to 1, i.e. at least 1 letter from the beginning of the term has to match. You can set `prefix_length` to 0 but this will have performance implications. Only your hardware, your setup and your dataset can show you exactly what those will be in practice in your case, i.e. try it :). However, be careful - Elasticsearch and Lucene devs set the default to 1 for a reason.

Here's a query which for me returns the suggestion result you're after on Elasticsearch 7.4.0 after I perform your setup steps.

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/test/_search' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
  "suggest": {
    "001" : {
      "text" : "rganic",
      "term" : {
        "field" : "word",
        "prefix_length": 0
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer if it's the relevant info :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the **CANDIDATE GENERATORS** with **phrase suggester** check this out from Elasticsearch in Action book page 444

> Having multiple generators and filters lets you do some neat tricks. For instance, if
> typos are likely to happen both at the beginning and end of words, you can use multi-
> ple generators to avoid expensive suggestions with low prefix lengths by using the
> reverse token filter, as shown in figure F.4.
> You’ll implement what’s shown in figure F.4 in listing F.4:
> ■ First, you’ll need an analyzer that includes the reverse token filter.
>
> ■ Then you’ll index the correct product description in two fields: one
> analyzed with the standard analyzer and one with the reverse analyzer.

From Elasticsearch docs

> The following example shows a phrase suggest call with two generators: the first one is using a field containing ordinary indexed terms, and the second one uses a field that uses terms indexed with a reverse filter (tokens are index in reverse order). This is used to overcome the limitation of the direct generators to require a constant prefix to provide high-performance suggestions. The `pre_filter` and `post_filter` options accept ordinary analyzer names.

So you can achieve this by using the `reverse` analyzer with the `post-filter` and `pre-filter`

And as you can see they said:

> This is used to overcome the limitation of the direct generators to require a constant prefix to provide high-performance suggestions.

Check this Figure from Elasticsearch In Action book I believe it will make the idea more clear.

[A screenshot from the book explains how elastic search will give us the correct phrase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDrh3.png)

For more information refer to the docs
[https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-suggesters-phrase.html#:~:text=The%20phrase%20suggester%20uses%20candidate,individual%20term%20in%20the%20text](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-suggesters-phrase.html#:%7E:text=The%20phrase%20suggester%20uses%20candidate,individual%20term%20in%20the%20text).

If explained the full idea then this will be a very long answer but I gave you the key and you can go and do your research about using the phrase suggester with multiple generators.